# Compose a query that runs whether or not the table exists

Tags: sql-server

This is a fun one.  I have a view that suddenly needs to run across different versions of the database (an external tool).  What I'd LIKE to do is just have one query that works correctly (using any manner of CASE/IF EXISTS or magic tricks with cross joins or what have you).

Basically, if a given table exists, I want to return a count of rows in that table... if it doesn't, I want to return NULL.

It's the "Table" version of this question, which deals with how to write a query whether or not a given column exists in the table: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66741/why-cant-i-use-a-case-statement-to-see-if-a-column-exists-and-not-select-from-i

I can't use a

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('possibleTable') 
THEN (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM possibleTable WHERE mycondition)
ELSE (SELECT NULL)
END
```

... because that gives an error when the table doesn't exist, because it tries to bind at compile time even though the code will never run if the table doesn't exist.

Basically I have to augment a CTE to include a count for a new table but not fail if the table isn't there.  Having to make another round-trip to the database to check if the table is there, and then run one of two different CTEs seems distasteful to me... but so far I haven't found any better way.

Just curious if anyone has any SQL magic that can make such a thing work, like that fun "CROSS JOIN" trick for dealing with a possibly missing column (which I'm also making use of).

Comment: You cannot do this with a query, but you *can* do it with a SQL procedure.  For instance, your `IF..ELSE..` example is actually a SQL *procedure* (or script) rather than a SQL query.  So, your example `IF..` procedure/script could be modified to do it.  But.. you can only define Views around single queries, they cannot be built on procedures/scripts.

Comment: Assume I cannot use a stored procedure, but I can just run any SQL script I want against the DB... I'm not sure I'm following how to do that (this is how I'm currently testing, just running a script in a Query Window of SQL Server Management Studio)... my issue is it's a LARGE script and I just want to add one more column to the result set that is either NULL or a COUNT, based on whether the table exists.

Comment: How about using dynamic SQL to select from the table? You could also call out to `sys.partitions` to get the count from the DMV rather than reading the whole table when it does exist. But more to the point, why are you writing code with hard-coded names for tables that might exist?

Comment: Can you not use `IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'Tablename') SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename ELSE SELECT NULL`

Comment: I can't find a way to get dynamic SQL to work INSIDE a CASE statement.  And the problem as presented is overly simplified... there is a FILTER on the COUNT (a WHERE clause).  The issue is that in later versions of the DB, data that used to be in table X is now in table X *and* table Y, and I need to account for both cases in the tool, which needs to be version agnostic.  I tried to distill the problem down here... in short, the partitions idea won't work for me, and the hard-coded table name is a given.

Comment: No, @M.Ali... if you try that on a database where 'Tablename' doesn't exist, you'll get an error when you try to run the script.... as indicated above in the original question.

Comment: Right, as @AaronBertrand says, the way to do this is through a script or procedure (not necessarily a *stored* procedure) that uses dynamic SQL.  That will work from an SSMS query window, but not within a View.

Comment: @pmbAustin no it will not throw an error if the table doesn't exists as it will never execute the select query.

Comment: @M.Ali you can't put that in a CASE statement or in a CTE, which is the entire point.  I'm trying to add a column to an existing LARGE query.  If I put an IF/THEN/ELSE I basically have to duplicate about a hundred lines of SQL, with just this one difference.  And that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid... all that code duplication.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were trying to use `CASE` instead of `IF`. You cannot use Dynamic SQL within `CASE` because `CASE` is an *expression* and dynamic SQL is implemented as a statement. You have to use it within an `IF` which is a statement that can contain other statements.

Comment: So basically, the answer is "This isn't possible and there's nothing clever or interesting you can do to get around this... your only choice is massive code duplication and/or an extra round-trip to the database from the tool to detect if the table is there and run different SQL based on that result".  I'll just delete this question, since there's no possible answer.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use a function?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_checktable] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @checktable nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @result int

    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].['+@checktable+']') AND type in (N'U'))
        set @result = 1 
    else 
        set @result = 0


    endsave:
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @result

END

GO
```

then use like

```
select case when dbo.fn_checktable('YOURTABLENAME') = 1 
    then (select top 1 'whatever' from YOURTABLENAME ) 
    else 'nothing' end as something
```

the result from select  dbo.fn_checktable('YOURTABLENAME') is 1 or 0.

But, maybe i missunderstood. You wrote "a count of rows"...hmmm, i think i need more input.

Comment: The main issue with this idea is that I have to modify the DB to use it (basically my tool has to install a function when it starts, and clean it up when it stops).  However, this is the closest thing to "working" that I've seen yet.  I've managed to code up a proof of concept and it seems to work. I just don't know if I'll be permitted to implement it since I have to install a function like this (the tool has, until now, been read/reporting only).  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe You can map a second DB or store the function in temp DB.